# Criar tabelas randomicamente

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

A minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Tenho uma tabela contendo 25 registros de nomes de pessoas. Porém preciso dividi-la em 5 grupos de 5 pessoas aleatoriamente.

Sendo uma tabela 'Grupo A' com 5 pessoas, outra tabela 'Grupo B' com 5 pessoas e assim por diante.

É necessário ser no SQL Server, pois a massa de dados é bem maior que essa. Alguém sabe como usar a função `rand()`?

Coloquei assim:

```
select * from pessoas order by RAND()
```

Mas como eu coloco, por exemplo, para separar em grupos de 5?

Comment: Há alguma necessidade específica pra que isso seja feito no SQL Server?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Uma coisa interessante a se ler: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/699/faq-da-comunidade . Quanto a sua dúvida, vc já tentou algo? Se sim, edite sua pergunta com o código que tentou, fica melhor para te ajudar. Outra coisa, para que você quer separar em outras tabelas os dados, algum motivo real para isso ou será que não tem algo melhor para fazer com isso?! O que precisa realmente fazer com os dados? Pode ser que um select * from tabela order by rand() pode resolver, depois no loop vc pode separar, já vai vir em ordem aleatória os dados mesmo.

Comment: Quando tiver alguma dúvida referente a utilização de determinado comando no SQL Server, basta clicar F1 sobre o comando que será aberto o helper do SQL Server, onde tem exemplos de como utilizar e explica todo comando.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que é o que espera.

```
DECLARE @nQtdeGrupo INT = 5

SELECT cNome
     , iGrupo 
  FROM (SELECT cNome  = PESSOAS.NOME
             , iGrupo = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID() DESC) % @nQtdeGrupo) + 1
          FROM PESSOAS
       ) tGrupo
 ORDER BY iGrupo
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando sua lógica você pega o resto da divisão por 5 que irá ficar entre um numero entre 0 e 5.

```
SELECT *, FLOOR((RAND() * 1481) % 5) AS grupo FROM pessoas ORDER BY grupo
```

Devido a função RAND retornar um núemro entre 0 e 1 é necessário multiplicar para conseguir um inteiro de numero grande.

[Código](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/734b2/5)

Comment: Se utilizar um atributo Id sequencial eu tentaria fazer o MOD por ele para ficar melhor distribuido, utilizando RAND um grupo pode ficar mais desbalanceado que outro.

Comment: Heat, o seu select está dando erro de conversão. Como o RAND gera um float, é preciso convertê-lo para int, antes de fazer a divisão, algo assim:

`SELECT FLOOR(CAST((RAND() * 1481) AS int) % 5)`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer a divisão, usando a função NTILE, exemplo:

```
DECLARE @Count int
       ,@MaxRowsPerTable int = 5

SELECT @Count = COUNT() FROM dbo.Pessoas

/* Número máximo de tabelas que serão criadas */
SET @MaxCreationTable = FLOOR(@Count / @MaxRowsPerTable)

SELECT NTILE(@MaxCreationTable) OVER (ORDER BY Nome) 'Grupo', Nome FROM Pessoas
```

Eu menciono quantas linhas terá por tabela, em seguida calculo o número máximo de tabelas que serão criadas e jogo esse valor dentro do parâmetro do NTILE. Isso permite criar um balanceamento quase perfeito (perfeito somente se o número de linhas for divisível pelo número total de linhas em uma tabela.

A partir daí, pode criar um `WHILE` responsável por criar tabelas dinâmicas com base no count e inserir os valores onde `COUNT` é igual ao Grupo de `NTILE`

Veja se isso atende a sua necessidade.